# My promise is undefined when getting dynamodb info for a key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I get undefined whenever I return the promise.

### Async Function to retrieve Item from ddb

```
async function getTask(){
    const userName = 'jared'; //key name
    const userTable = 'todoUsers'; //table name
async function getTask(){  //get list of tasks for key
   const params = {    //params for dynamodb.get
    Key:{
        "username": userName
    },
    TableName: userTable,
    ConsistentRead: true,
};
 return await dynamodb.update(params).promise().then(response => { //returning response
 return response;
}, error =>{
    console.log('There is an error getting task: ', error);
});

    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided seems to be incorrect, since you define getTask() twice. I also don't understand why you `await` and then use a `then`.

Try this and see if the return is defined:

```
  public static async getTask() {
    const userName = 'jared'; //key name
    const userTable = 'todoUsers'; //table name
    const params = {
      //params for dynamodb.get
      Key: {
        username: userName
      },
      TableName: userTable,
      ConsistentRead: true
    };
    return documentClient.update(params).promise();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked after I used try catch.

```
async function getTasks(){
    const userName = 'jared';
    const userTable = 'todoUsers';
    try {
        var params = {
            KeyConditionExpression: 'username = :user',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':user': userName
            },
            TableName: userTable
        };
        var result = await dynamodb.query(params).promise()
        return JSON.stringify(result.Items);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }


}
```